# Does being a subspace locally imply a global version?

Tags: general-topology

$Y$ is a subset of topology space $(X,\tau_X)$, with a topology $\tau_Y$. $\{U_{\lambda}\}$ is an open covering of $X$, and for all $\lambda$, the subspace topology of $Y\cap U_{\lambda}$ inheriting from $Y$ coincides with that from $U_{\lambda}$. Can we conclude that $(Y,\tau_Y)$ is a subspace of $(X,\tau_X)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R$, and let $\tau_X$ be the Sorgenfrey (lower limit) topology on $\Bbb R$. Let $Y=X$, and let $\tau_Y$ have as base the intervals $[x,y)$ such that $0\ne x<y$ and the intervals $(x,y)$ such that $x<0<y$. (Thus, the two topologies differ only in that $0$ is a two-sided limit in $\langle Y,\tau_Y\rangle$.) Let $U_0=(\leftarrow,0)$ and $U_1=[0,\to)$; $\{U_0,U_1\}$ is a $\tau_X$-open cover of $X$. $U_0$ inherits the same topology from $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$, as does $U_1$, but $\langle Y,\tau_Y\rangle$ is not a subspace of $\langle X,\tau_X\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that $Y$ is not a subspace of $X$. For instance, let $X=\{1,2\}$ endowed with the discrete topology, $Y=\{1,2\}$ endowed with the antidiscrete topology, $U_1=\{1\}$, and $U_2=\{2\}$.